# modify detached html element (change img.src) with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to prefix all `src` of `img` tags in an html element.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var html = ...;
$('img[src]', html).each(function(a) {
  var $t = $(this);
  var oldsrc = $t.attr('src');
  $t.attr({src: prefix + oldsrc});
});
```

Another alternative

```
_.each($('img', html), function(img) {
  var src = base + $(img).attr('src');
  img.src = src;
});
```

When I run this code on the dom it works flawless. But when I try to run this against an detached `html` object it won't work.
This updates the `img` within the closure, but does not update html the `img`s within `html`.

What am I missing here?

The solution does not need to use jquery (can also be plain javascript or backbone)

Comment: Is `html` a string or really a DOM element? If it is a DOM element, it will work...

Comment: What do you mean, "detached html object"? How can you tell it doesn't work?  It certainly should.

Comment: thank you. `html = $(html);` fixed this

Comment: You can post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Felix Kling pointed out: html needs to be a DOM Element, but it was a String

```
html = $(html);
```

fixed the issue